# How do I display the upper case greek letter delta in a label in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I want to display a formula in a label that goes like:

|delta X| = (G - S + F)

where the word delta in the above should actually be the upper case greek letter delta (which looks like a triangle). I tried to use GnuGetText for Delphi to translate it like this but it came out as a question mark:

|? X| = (G - S + F)

Since [Gorm](http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2014/07/05/gorm-experimental-release/) (which is written with Delphi XE) displays the strings correctly, I guess a unicode aware Delphi version would be a solution. Unfortunately I can't go that way because this would break existing code.

Another solution would be a picture of the the formula which would avoid the issue.

Are there any other options?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this works but I would prefer a solution that does not require yet another component pack. (I got it from here http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tntunicodecontrols/index )

Comment: Δ: U+0394: GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA

Comment: @dummzeuch You want to have your cake and eat it.

Comment: You could create a WMF/EMF file with the formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is using a font that supports Greek charset

```
Label1.Font.Name := 'Tahoma'; // Arial, Verdana ... one that supports Greek charset
Label1.Font.Charset := GREEK_CHARSET;
Label1.Caption := '|'#196'X| = (G - S + F)'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to display international text in a Delphi application there are three primary options available to you:

1. Use a version of Delphi that supports Unicode (2009+).
2. Use the TNT Unicode controls.
3. Paint the text yourself by calling `DrawTextW` or some similar Win32 Unicode API.